# Exporting PATH in profile

Tags: bash

This may sound incredibly stupid, but for whatever reasons, I have two of the exact exports:

```
#does not work
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/dev1/test/jsunpack-n-read-only/depends/js-1.8.0-rc1-src/Linux_All_OPT.OBJ
#works
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/dev1/test/jsunpack-n-read-only/depends/js-1.8.0-rc1-src/Linux_ALL_OPT.OBJ
```

they were both created differently, one is generated by using `pwd` and the other was generated with me hardcoding it. Do you guys see any difference here? :s I'm thoroughly confused. Is it misreading characters?

Comment: is the last element in your path a dir or an .obj file? Paths' don't respect files. Else try piping both thru `od -c` **at their point of creation** to see if there is anything, like a Ctrl-M embedded and not visible. Good luck.

Comment: Turns out it was 'All' and 'ALL'

Comment: Perhaps acquire the habit of using `diff` in such cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is `"ALL"` and `"All"`, case is everything ;-)

Comment: omfg.... t.t you are a life saver!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you have the right approach. My suggestion is to keep your `$PATH` minimal or at least reasonably small. (And likewise for `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if needed).

Practically, I suggest you to have a `$HOME/bin/` directory (which you add once to your `PATH`), and to either put your programs there, or at least a symlink to the absolute path of some executable program (or some executable script).